# How do I apply an inverse transformation in scales functions (ggplot2)?

Tags: r, ggplot2, scale, axis

I have the following example code:

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(price, carat)) +
geom_bin2d() +
scale_x_continuous(trans = "log10") +
scale_y_continuous(trans = "log10")
```

What can I do to get the inverse transformation?

Comment: Are you looking for a general solution to apply an inverse of any transformation, or are you specifically looking for the `scales::exp_trans(base = 10)` transformation? It is the inverse of `log10`, but for most everyday numbers this will blow up b/c R's integer type (which `diamond$price` is in) maxes out around 2 billion, so any input over ~9  (becoming 10^9 = 1B) will be out of range.

Comment: If you are looking for a general solution then maybe this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53052874/define-new-scales-axis-tranform-for-ggplot/53053377#53053377

Comment: Thank you both for the info. So , there is not implicit arguments or functions to do that, isn't it?